# bit masking/shifting in mips assembly language?

Tags: mips

The requirements of the program are posted in the code below along with my solution. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and show me how I can fix it? I keep getting 0 as a result for every input I put in. For the most part, I believe I am masking wrong rather than shifting the bits incorrectly.

```
    ##########################################################################

############################
# prompt user to enter an integer, read the integer, and display a 0 if the bits at the
# 16 and 256 place value positions of the integer are both 1 and display a 1 otherwise
############################ data segment ################################
            .data
outputLegend1:      .asciiz "0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1\n"
outputLegend2:      .asciiz "1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1\n\n"
inputPrompt:        .asciiz "Enter integer: "
outputLabel:        .asciiz "Integer entered is of type "
############################ code segment ################################
            .text
            .globl main
main:
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, outputLegend1        
            syscall         # print output legend part 1
            la $a0, outputLegend2        
            syscall         # print output legend part 2
            la $a0, inputPrompt        
            syscall         # print integer prompt
            li $v0, 5
            syscall         # read integer
            move $t0, $v0       # save integer read in $t0
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, outputLabel        
            syscall         # print output label

            li $v0, 1

            ##########################################################
            # Insert NO MORE THAN 6 lines of code that involve ONLY 
            #   bit manipulating instructions (ANDing, ORing, XORing,
            #   NORing and shifting - only whatever that are needed)
            # so that the program will work just like the sample runs 
            # shown at the bottom (some blank lines edited out).








#my solution


            sll $t1,$t1,4
            andi $t2,$t1,1
            sll $t2,$t2,4
            andi $t3,$t2,1
            xor $a0, $t2,$t3






            syscall         # display desired output

                    ##########################################################

            li $v0, 10      # exit gracefully
                    syscall

########################## sample test runs ##############################
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 0
# Integer entered is of type 1
# -- program is finished running --
# 
# Reset: reset completed.
# 
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 16
# Integer entered is of type 1
# -- program is finished running --
# 
# Reset: reset completed.
# 
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 256
# Integer entered is of type 1
# -- program is finished running --
# 
# Reset: reset completed.
# 
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 272
# Integer entered is of type 0
# -- program is finished running --
# 
# Reset: reset completed.
# 
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 12349876
# Integer entered is of type 0
# -- program is finished running --
# 
# Reset: reset completed.
# 
# 0 = both bits at 16 & 256 place value positions are 1
# 1 = bits at 16 & 256 place value positions NOT both 1
# 
# Enter integer: 12346789
# Integer entered is of type 1
# -- program is finished running --
# 
######################## end sample test runs ############################
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea (but lots of typos) so keep going!

---

There's nothing interesting in `$t1` when you first shift it.  I think you wanted to shift `$t0` initially, but into `$t1` so you still have the original value of the user input for a later operation.

---

Watch your register usages:

- you need to *source* registers that have been *target*ed earlier in your program,
- you need to use a new/different register for target, if you're going to want some original/sourced value later on (don't wipe out values you still need),
- you can't simply source new registers when you need old/original values

Use single-step to verify that you're getting the intermediate values you're expecting after each instruction.  If not then check to see if the instruction is sourcing the right registers, or, maybe the source register was wiped out by an earlier instruction!

---

Also, you're shifting left when you want to shift right...

---

You're just guessing at what register to use when.  So, here's an approach that might help you get away from the confusion due to unfamiliar assembly.

Try writing your code in C ***using [Three address code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code)*** — for this assignment, it won't take much, about 5 lines!  But this will help you understand which variable to use when.  (Make sure your C three address code works — test & debug it somewhere, if necessary an online C compiler.)

Next, assign (create a map) all of the those C (TAC) variables to MIPS registers — before you write any instructions.

Finally, write assembly instructions, that respect/mimic those three address codes, using your map of variables to registers.